# TF30177:Team Project Creation Failed(TFS 2012 and Sql server 2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, tfs

Error 
The Project Creation Wizard encountered an error while creating reports to the SQL Server Reporting Services on http://www.tfsserver/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx.

Explanation 
The Project Creation Wizard encountered a problem while creating reports on the SQL Server Reporting Services on http://www.tfsserver/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx. The reason for the failure cannot be determined at this time. Because the operation failed, the wizard was not able to finish creating the SQL Server Reporting Services site.

User Action 
Contact the administrator for the SQL Server Reporting Services on http://www.tfserver/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx to confirm that the SQL Server Reporting Services server is running and you have sufficient privileges to create a project. Your user account on SQL Server Reporting Services must have Content Manager permission to create a new project. Also, you might find additional helpful information in the project creation log. The log shows each action taken by the wizard at the time of the failure and may include additional details about the error.

I am using TFS 2012 and Sql server 2012 all running under service accounts and given the both service accounts as TFS Content Manager Permissions still isuse exits.

Frist Installed Sql server 2012 Version

Second Installed the TFS 2012 and try to create the team project

Please help me to fix the issue ?

[image: TFS 2012 Team Project Creation Error]

Comment: On the TFS app tier, use the TFS administration console to setup or fix the reporting feature. If you don't need reporting, disable it by clearing the `Use Reporting` checkbox.

Comment: Thank you KMoraz, I want to use the reporting feature for TFS Project collection for Management reporting Purpose.I will try to disable the reporting in App Tier and create the Team Project. But i am surprised why i am getting this error even though we have proper permissions on all service accounts ,any info on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The project creation log should contain more details, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you I got help from  Cece Dong from MSDN Forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0180af87-4ff8-401a-ab23-94f3040f0cfe/tf30177team-project-creation-failedtfs-2012-and-sql-server-2012?forum=tfsadmin#0180af87-4ff8-401a-ab23-94f3040f0cfe   I did below two things as suggested by Cece Dong from MSDN Forums and fixed the issue.     1. cleaned the Cache folder on your client computer. The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache.

2. Removed the windows credentials in Control Panel--Credential Manager--Windows Credentials

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem while trying to create a new team project on TFS 2013, Update 3.  For me, the solution posted at Michael Ayvazyan's blog fixed it:

http://ayvazyan.net/2013/02/tfs-2012-migrated-from-tfs-2010-project-creation-fails/

I have repeated the solution below.  Run the following SQL Statements on your TFS database server:

```
USE master
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_notify TO  [NT SERVICE\ReportServer]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs TO  [NT SERVICE\ReportServer]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting TO  [NT SERVICE\ReportServer]
GO

USE msdb
GO
-- Permissions for SQL Agent SP's
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_help_category TO  [NT SERVICE\ReportServer]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_add_category TO  [NT SERVICE\ReportServer]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at the log provided at the link in the wizard, I found an entry of 
*"Exception Message: The item '/Tfs2010ReportDS' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/Tfs2010ReportDS' cannot be found. (type SoapException)SoapException ...."*

I found a solution to this at http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2012/08/tfs-itemnotfoundexception-on-reporting.html...

The gist of which is

1. Go to your team foundation server
2. Open the administration console.
3. Click on Reporting
4. Click on Edit
5. Click on Reports Tab
6. Enter the credential for the Reports
7. Save Click on Start Jobs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact error message.  **Solved it** by -->

1. Login your team foundation server
2. **Open** the **Team foundation administration console**.
3. **Click** on **Reporting** (Left side)
4. **Click** on **Stop Jobs** (Right side)
5. **Click** on **Start Jobs** (Right side)